# casting in order by using Ransack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, ransack

I'm using ransack for auto generate 'order by' headers columns

I have a model client, and the client has one Document that have an attr called number:

```
class Client < User

has_one :document

end

class Document 

belongs_to :client

end
```

I have view with a table, with attributes from both models:

```
<th> <%= sort_link @search, :email, "Email"  %></th>
<th> <%= sort_link @search, 'profile_first_name', "Name"  %></th>
<th> <%= sort_link @search, 'document_number', "ID"  %></th>
```

My problem, is that 'document_number' is a `string` field in the db, so if I have 3 users with: "1" "100"  "2"  I want the order:

`1 2 100`

but I get `1 100 2`

note: I also can have letters in this field like 'A123', I don't care about the order in this case, I'm using Postgres and rails 4.1

Comment: try to use `to_i` on the string values

Comment: By "don't care" do you mean that `'A1'` and `'B1'` should be considered equal for sorting purposes? How about `'A1B1'` and `A11`?

Comment: I only care about the values that can be parsed as numbers, the remaining could be in at beginning or in the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this  removing ransack and use in a mix the order string of Postgres and the LENGTH function Posgrest

So to simplify I can do:

```
Client.joins(:document).order("LENGTH(documents.number) ASC, documents.number").pluck(:number)
```

and get `["1", "2", "22", "99", "100"....`

a simply explanation https://gist.github.com/edymerchk/e5d5985c8abe96ab92da